# how to compare structure members in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, structure

I have the following code snippet. I'm trying to create a function that compares that values of array and array2. The function com_read(); loads values array2 and I'm not allowed to modify this function. So I need to compare the two arrays after calling com_read(); but I'm not sure how to do it since I'm not that familiar with structures in C. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define ARRAY_LENGTH(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

uint8_t array[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05 };
uint8_t array2[5];

uint16_t sineLookupTable[] = {128, 218, 255, 218, 128, 37, 0, 37 };

#define test_failure 0;
#define test_success 1;

typedef struct
{
    int dr_assert;
    int dr_fail;
} dr_result_t;

typedef struct 
{
    uint8_t* Firstbuff;
    uint16_t Firstbuff_size;
    uint8_t *Secondbuff;
    uint16_t Secondbuff_size;
    dr_result_t result;

} dr_config_data;

struct i2c_open
{
    dr_config_data initconfig;
    dr_result_t expectedResult;
};

struct i2c_open readDATA[1] =
{
    {{array, ARRAY_LENGTH(array),array2, ARRAY_LENGTH(array2)}, 0x01}
};

int com_read(uint8_t id, dr_config_data* data) {
    int status = test_failure;

    //do stuff
    status = test_success;
}


int main() {
    // printf() displays the string inside quotation

    int result = 0;
    dr_result_t result2;

    result = com_read(0, &readDATA[0].initconfig);
    result2 = readDATA[0].expectedResult;
    printf("result2 = %d\n", result2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ... create a function that compares that values of array and array2.

Since the 2 arrays:

- Lack any padding in the elements.
- Are simple integers.
- The same size.
- The same type.

... use `memcmp()`.

```
array[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05 };
uint8_t array2[5];

bool equal = memcmp(array, array2, sizeof array) == 0;
```

---

If the above conditions are not met, code may need a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

I do not exactly understand the structure of the code and your question. But since `array` and `array2` are global variables, you can compare their content simply by accesing their elements using `array[i]` and `array2[i]`, where `i` is the index.

If you would like to access them through the struct, you can access struct elements using the dot notataion like `data->Firstbuff[i]`, where `data` is the pointer to the struct. The arrow `->` is used instead of the `.`, because `data` is a pointer. You could also use `(*data).Firstbuff[i]` to first derefence the pointer and then access struct's field.

Another problem I currently see with this code is that values of `array2` are never set, which means all its elements are equals to 0.

Comment: thanks, you are right, I didn't realize they are both global.